# How to use fork of ES6 npm package?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, fork, pull-request

I often find myself in the situation where an npm package does exactly what I need, but has a bug or missing feature that blocks me from using it directly. So I fork it and make a pull request with what I need.

The problem occurs when the maintainer of the package is too busy to merge my PR, so I'm just stuck with my fork. I can't have my project dependency point directly to the github repo of the fork, as the npm package usually has some kind of compile/transpile step. I can publish the fork under a new package name, but then I have to maintain it.

**Is there a better way to use my fork of the package?**

(To clarify, I do not want to use `npm link` for development. I want the package referenced permanently so anyone else can clone my project and run `npm install` to get it working.)

Comment: I would fork the project, create a `dist/` folder and run everything necessary to build the project. Include the output file(s) and put them in your forked repo. Then, in `npm` include the project as a git repo dependency. `npm install --save git://github.com/name/name.git`. This will require you to do the minimum of merging back from the source in case the original owner updates and running the build again.

Comment: a good option in this case is patch-package https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

disclaimer: I wrote it

Comment: That's genius! This should definitely be an answer to this question, if only it weren't closed..